# Is there any way to view the source for built-in powershell cmdlets?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-cmdlet

I want to modify the code used in compare-object (so that I use the same algorithm for comparison, but modify output and possibly add some more to it). Is there any way to view the code that is used for this, or would I just have to guess? This could be useful incase I want to modify other cmdlets in the future.

Comment: If you want to modify the arguments or output for a built-in cmdlet, you may want to take a look at [proxy functions](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2009/01/04/extending-and-or-modifing-commands-with-proxies.aspx).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use an application like dotpeek to reflect the code of

```
Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Utility.dll
```

[image]